# VB.NET Kill multi process

Tags: vb.net

I use this code to kill a specific process :

```
Dim pProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")

For Each p As Process In pProcess
    p.Kill()
```

But how can I kill multi process using the same code ? like notepad & word ?

Comment: You repeat your code for each process in question?! Note that h cod you show, will kill all instances of notepad. Be careful why you do here, users will likely use data.

Comment: I don't understand " For each p as press in pProcess" , how this can be changed for another process

Comment: No, you copy all the lines and replace "notepad" with "winword". To be honest, you should first learn more about the vb.net programming language, it seems.

Comment: I'm still beginner in vb.net . If i do so , it would conflict , because pProcess is used before for Notepad . I can make a new varible called pProcess2 , but i don't understand for each P from pProcess , from where that P came ?

Answer (score 1):

... I would recommend, as @Christian K recommended, that you study up more on .Net because most programmers don't like just killing processes, but you could do what you're looking to do by creating a subroutine:

```
Sub KillProcess(ByVal ProcessName As String)
    Dim pProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName)

    pProcess(0).Kill()
End Sub
```

And then you would use it like this:

```
    KillProcess("notepad")
    KillProcess("winword")
```

Hope this helps